# Parsing Nested JSon File in Xamarin Forms

Tags: json, xamarin

I am developing a cross platform app using Xamarin. The data source is a JSON file which contains some words and their rhymes as shown below. I have to read the words from JSON file and to do that I have designed a model class "WordRhyme.cs". [image: Output]. My code is working fine but however for some reasons I cannot retrieve the Rhymes for each word. I have been trying to find a solution for last three days but no luck. As Rhymes is returning a List, I have also tried to replace the Labels with a List which is nested inside the words list but that's not working as well (xaml coded is added below). Also is there a way to only select a few records from JSON as it might have hundreds but I want to display a few. I have not programmed in Xamarin before so googling to learn.

**json1.json**

```
{
  "words": [

    {
      "word": "coffee",
      "syllables": 2,
      "topic": "Food and drink",
      "rhymes": [
        {
          "word": "toffee",
          "score": 385,
          "numSyllables": 2
        },
        {
          "word": "naafi",
          "score": 178,
          "numSyllables": 2
        },
        {
          "word": "tophi",
          "score": 172,
          "numSyllables": 2
        },
        {
          "word": "sofie",
          "score": 75,
          "numSyllables": 2
        },
          {
          "word": "yoffie",
          "numSyllables": 2
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      "word": "Cat",
      "syllables": 2,
      "topic": "Animals",
      "rhymes": [
        {
          "word": "Hat",
          "score": 385,
          "numSyllables": 2
        },
        {
          "word": "Fat",
          "score": 178,
          "numSyllables": 2
        },
        {
          "word": "Mat",
          "score": 172,
          "numSyllables": 2
        },
        {
          "word": "coffey2",
          "score": 152,
          "numSyllables": 2
        },
        {
          "word": "toffy2",
          "score": 119,
          "numSyllables": 2
        }      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**WordRhyme.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace JsonTest2.Models
{

    public class Rhyme
    {
        public string word { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }
        public int numSyllables { get; set; }
    }

    public class Word
    {
        public string word { get; set; }
        public int syllables { get; set; }
        public string topic { get; set; }
        public List<Rhyme> rhymes { get; set; }
    }

    public class WordRhymes
    {
        public List<Word> words { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="JsonTest2.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="30" Text="Rhyming Words JSON Parsing" FontSize="25" />
                    <ListView x:Name="listViewWords" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Footer="" HasUnevenRows="True">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding word}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding syllables}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Orange"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding topic}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding rhymes.word}" Grid.Row="3" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding rhymes.score}" Grid.Row="4" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding rhymes.numSyllables}" Grid.Row="5" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <BoxView HeightRequest="2" Margin="0,10,10,0" BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using JsonTest2.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
namespace JsonTest2
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetJsonData();
        }

        void GetJsonData()
        {
            string jsonFileName = "json1.json";
            WordRhymes ObjWordList = new WordRhymes();
            var assembly = typeof(Page1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list  
                ObjWordList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WordRhymes>(jsonString);
            }
            //Binding listview with json string   
            listViewWords.ItemsSource = ObjWordList.words;
        }
    }
}
```

**Nested ListView Page2Json.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="JsonTest2.Page2Json">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="30" Text="Rhyming Words JSON Parsing" FontSize="25" />
                    <ListView x:Name="listViewWords" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Footer="" HasUnevenRows="True">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding word}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding syllables}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Orange"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding topic}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <ListView x:Name="listViewRhymes" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding listViewWords.rhymes}">
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <ViewCell>
                                                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding rhymes.word}"></Label>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding rhymes.score}"></Label>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding rhymes.numSyllables}"></Label>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </ViewCell>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                                        </ListView>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding rhymes.word}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <BoxView HeightRequest="2" Margin="0,10,10,0" BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button x:Name="nextButton" Text="Next" Clicked="NextButton_Clicked"></Button>
                        <Button x:Name="backButton" Text="Back" Clicked="BackButton_Clicked"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: is the problem parsing the json (which has nothing to do with Xamarin) or displaying it?  You need to narrow that down first.  Further, nesting ListView is a HORRIBLE idea.  Finally, your outer StackLayout and Grid really don't seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: @Jason Can you please explain a bit more why it is a problem with parsing JSON file? The classes I have designed have all fields/attributes with correct data types. The WordRhymes and Word classes are parsed correctly I guess as they are able to retrieve the data. Yes, I know using nested ListViews is not a good idea but for the sake of getting my code working, I have tried it.

Comment: I didn't say it was.  I was asking YOU.  Your question title specifically says "parsing nested json" but the body of the question implies a problem with the UI.  Those are TWO completely different things.  You need to figure out which is the real problem.  It should be fairly trivial to determine if your json is getting properly deserialized into your model.

Comment: @Jason, I think it might be a problem with both and that's why I posted all the code. I will check it again thanks for your help.

Comment: @Aisha Hi ,if answer be helpful , remember to mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the inner list in Page2Json.xaml your itemsource is binded with `listViewWords.rhymes` which I think should only be `rhymes` and even inside this listview labels should not be binded with `rhymes.something` rather they should be `something`
here is the updated code that I think should work

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listViewRhymes" ItemsSource="{Binding rhymes}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding word}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding score}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding numSyllables}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

These changes are considering your page2json.xaml.cs is same as page1json.xaml.cs

Comment: I will try it but can you please check the WordRhyme.cs file and tell if it is designed correctly?

Comment: why don't you just verify the data yourself?  Use the debugger to inspect `ObjWordList` and verify that it contains the data you expect.

Comment: @Aisha your classes look fine to me in the first look but as Jason said you can verify the same using debugger very easily.

Comment: I am doing it now. Thanks

Comment: The JSON file is being parsed correctly, I figured it out so the problem is now with UI. Whats the preferable control to bind nested JSON? If my using nested listview it is only displaying first record.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of screen?